# Enable Multi Select option in bootstrap check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am creating a web application in which bootstrap is used for design. And I am creating a check box using `bootstrap.check-box.js` and `bootstrap.check-box.css`

```
Using the code
```

`$('input[type="checkbox"]').checkbox();`

my html code is

```
 <div id="popover-cnt-detect" class="hide">
     <ul class="detectul">
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Frontal">&nbsp;Frontal Face</label></div></li>
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Profile"> &nbsp;Profile Face</label></div></li>
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Eyes">&nbsp;Eyes</label> </div></li>
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Head">&nbsp;Head</label></div></li>
     </ul>
     <button type="submit" class="btn alert-continue-btn ">Continue</button>
 </div>
```

This is the jquery code for popping up that checkbox div..

```
$("#detect").popover({
        html: true, 
        content: function() { return $('#popover-cnt-detect').html(); }
    });
    $("#detect").click(function()
    {
    $(this).popover({
            html: true, 
            trigger: 'click',
            content: function() { return $('#popover-cnt-detect').html(); }
        });

    return false;
    });
```

Now , What I need to know is that this check-box is single-select only,I couldn't select multiple options in that check box.

So,Please help me friends by telling how to provide multiple select option in `check-boxes`..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Provide us a fiddle...

Comment: sorry.. I didn't get you

Comment: Update this fiddle according to your need http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/H2Bep/

Comment: jsFiddle is a place where you post example of your code and it work. Check my answer to see that example

Answer (score 1):

Working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/f2jg6/)

### Code

#### HTML

```
<div id="popover-cnt-detect" class="hide">
     <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox select-all">Select All</label></div>
     <ul class="detectul">
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Frontal">&nbsp;Frontal Face</label></div></li>
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Profile"> &nbsp;Profile Face</label></div></li>
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Eyes">&nbsp;Eyes</label> </div></li>
         <li class="listitems"> <div class="checkbox"><label><input name="check[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Head">&nbsp;Head</label></div></li>
     </ul>
     <button type="submit" class="btn alert-continue-btn ">Continue</button>
 </div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('change','.select-all',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('[name="check[]"]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });
    } else {
        $('[name="check[]"]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
});
```

### Explanation

We add a new checkbox with the class `select-all` and listen to the `change` event of that checkbox. If it is checked, JavaScript will search for all the checkboxes with the name `checkbox[]` and make it checked using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)`('checked', true)`. If it is unchecked it will uncheck the checkboxes using `prop('checked', false)`.

Comment: sorry,this is not my requirement. In bootstrap, multi selection is not possible in those check boxes,I could select only one checkbox at a time.. Please help me.